# Exprort Bonitasoft .bos for intelij

Tags: jbpm, business-process-management, ibm-bpm, bonita

Export a project in bonitasoft an run it in intelij

Hello, do you know if i can run in intelij the export of bonitasoft?
I export the project but the files i dont think that can run in intelij.